# How to distribute header level discount across detail items

Tags: sql, sql-server, oracle, sql-server-2008, oracle10g

I have 2 tables, header and detail. As shown below the header table will have 1 record and the detail table will have multiple records. Now there is a discount on header level. I would like to distribute the discount on each detail item according to their weight and get the actual rate.

[image]

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to allocate discount based on `(rate * qty)` as percentage of the transaction total:

```sql
WITH transaction_totals AS (

    SELECT   h.header_id
            ,h.discount
            ,SUM(d.rate * d.ty) AS total
    FROM header h
        INNER JOIN detail d
            ON h.header_id = d.header_id
    GROUP BY h.header_id
            ,h.discount

)

SELECT   d.item
        ,d.rate
        ,d.qty
        ,d.total
        --,d.total / tt.total AS DetailPctTotal
        ,tt.discount * (d.total / tt.total) AS DetailDiscount
FROM detail d
    INNER JOIN transaction_totals tt
        ON d.header_id = tt.header_id
;
```